# Insert my site's HTML into another static page

Tags: html, include, mechanicalturk

I would like to use my website on mechanical turk.

But because I can only enter static HTML into mechanical turk's description.

I need to somehow place my website there. How do I do that?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "I can only have 1 html on mturk"?  What does this mean?

Comment: I have one content editor, of which I can edit the HTML source. But I want not to just have a one static html page, I want to "stream" my website into there.

Comment: You could use an `iframe` if they allow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't effectively do this, with one exception.

See if they permit the [`iframe` element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/iframe.html).  If they do, then you can use an `iframe` to reference your web site.  Be warned, cookie behavior and other things may cause interaction problems on your site.  `iframe` is also considered a security risk, so I would not be surprised if they don't allow it.

**Your actual best bet is going to be merely linking to your site from the description field you're given.**

Comment: What would you think about Ajax requesting the site from the html?

Comment: You could not use ajax because of [the Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  Even then, I highly, highly doubt that they would permit arbitrary Javascript to be entered, as that would be one of the ultimate security risks.

Comment: I think I've found my solution. But yours great too.